# Pass dynamic value from html table row to javascript url.action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I want to pass the selected cell value from `@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.year)` to the `Url.Action` I have created in the javascript.

My controller has two parameters one is a static name and the other is year that is dynamically gotten from the row selected.

Codes for the table:

```
<table id="name" border=1 width="50%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="see">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.year)</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Codes for javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urls = {
       view: '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("(actionName)", "(controller)", new { name = "Mary", year = (this is what idk)}))'
    };

    $document.ready(function()
    {
        $('#see').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').load(urls.view, function () {    
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult actionName(string name, string year)
{
    var query = new aquery();
    var response = query.Fetch(name, year);
    return View(response);
}
```

Calls a popup form which has

```
<form id="", action="@html.raw(@url.action(same thing here as my previous main page. what do i put for the year here now?))">
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense and there seems no need for javascript based on the code you have shown. Are you wanting to generate a link in each row of a table?

Comment: Then show your script and the html for one row in your table

Comment: Still not clear what your trying to do. Your `foreach` loop creates multiple rows that display the year. Which row do you want to get the year for. Why are you attempting (incorrectly) to generate a url (what do you intend to do with it)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke the row that I click on. that's the year i want to get. the url is meant to pop up a dialog box with retrieved information. that part is working already. i just need help to retrieve the selected year.

Comment: `$('tr').click(function() { var year = $(this).children('td').last().text(); })` to get the year, but you need to show the controller method your calling and the script that calls the dialog

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay now how do i pass in the value - selected year  and add it inside the the url.action part where year = ?

Comment: _"but you need to show the controller method your calling and the script that calls the dialog"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid html because of the duplicate `id="see"` attributes you adding to the buttons in the `foreach` loop. First change it to use a class name instead, and add the `type="button"` because the default is `"submit"`

```
<button type="button" class="see">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.year)</button>
```

The the script should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $document.ready(function()
  {
    var dialog = $('#dialog'); // cache elements you may repeatedly use
    var url = '@Url.Action("actionName")'; // add the controller name if its in a different controller
    $('.see').click(function () { // change selector to use the class name
      dialog.load(url, { name: 'Mary', year: $(this).text() });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Side note: your method parameter should be `int year`, not `string year` and your method should return a `PartialView(response)`, not `View(response)`

Comment: i made the changes, but now there is another error as i have the same codes in another cshtml file cause of the dialog pop up box

Comment: That's a different question :) But you can use `@Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", new { year = ViewBag.Year }))` and in the `actionName()` method add `ViewBag.Year = year;` before you return the view.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add @Html.Raw before @Url.Action, because, as you can see in the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), @Url.Action returns a String

```
var urls = { view: '@Url.Action("actionName", 
                                "controllerName", 
                                 new {name = "mary", year = ?})' }
```